# Message specific user in a Phonegap/Cordova app using SignalR 2

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, cordova, signalr, signalr-hub

I am attempting to create a real-time communication capability for a Phonegap/Cordova app. I am using SignalR 2 to handle the communication.

The thing I am struggling with is getting a message to a particular user. Every single example out there shows saving Context.User.Identity.Name, which is useless to me because the remote site's User.Identity context is not shared by my phonegap app.

In essence, I am not authenticating a user in the traditional sense, so I need another way of linking the SignalR connectionID with the username I pass along.

Taken from the official ASP.NET signalr Examples, I have the following code which overrides the OnConnected event. Unfortunately it takes no parameters and expects User.Identity to be not null:

```
public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        using (var db = new UserContext())
        {
            // Retrieve user.
            var user = db.Users
                .Include(u => u.Rooms)
                .SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == Context.User.Identity.Name);

            // If user does not exist in database, must add.
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = new User()
                {
                    UserName = Context.User.Identity.Name
                };
                db.Users.Add(user);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                // Add to each assigned group.
                foreach (var item in user.Rooms)
                {
                    Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, item.RoomName);
                }
            }
        }
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
```

Now, maybe what I'd need is to have a version of this method that takes a string as a parameter and then I'd use that as my user identifier.

But how to go about that?

Comment: Well thanks for the upvotes anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new IUserIdProvider for the user and use dependency injection to register your provider and use it.

```
public interface IUserIdProvider
{
    string GetUserId(IRequest request);
}
```

Register your provider with Global Host

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IUserIdProvider), () => new MyIdProvider());
```

Usage:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string userId, string message)
    {
        Clients.User(userId).send(message);
    }
}
```

Taken from: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#IUserIdProvider